# Backbone view initialization code

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have some backbone views that depend on jQuery plugins like:

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999")
```

Just wondering where the recommended place to add this. The render call?

```
class App.Views.Chrome extends Backbone.View
   render: ->
      header = new App.Views.Header()
      @$el.html header.render().el
      $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999")
      @
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly where I would put it.  This way, every time you render this view, the mask is applied at that time, and any code or UI experience that depends on this can depend on the fact that it has been applied.

I tend to place lots of things in `render` code, for instance, keeping cached copies of jQuery objects that point to a specific node or collection of nodes, so that I don't have to look them up with a jQuery selector every time I reference them, indicating that they are jQuery objects by prefacing their name with `$`.

`@$divMain = @$el.find('#divMain');`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the perspective. Coming from a very opinionated Rails world, it's nice to get other people's perspectives on best practices in Backbone.

Comment: You can use [`@$('#divMain')`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) instead of `@$el.find('#divMain')`.